# powershell - getting last users last login from local server

Tags: powershell

I have been working on a script to show the the last login of each of the users that have been logging into their terminal server.

The script works if they are not on a domain but when they are on a domain, it would show users that have not logged into that particular server.

Is there a way for me to edit the script to where it only shows users that have logged into that specific server?

Here is the code:

```
#This script will check which users have logged on in the last X days
#Set Variables
#Change the number in the parenthesis after adddays to change how far back 
to filter
#example (get-date).adddays(-30) gets all logins for the last 30 days from 
today (-60) would be the last 60 days

$AuditDate = Get-Date (get-date).adddays(-30) -format "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss 
tt"
$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$CurrentDate = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d"


#Delete any previously created files
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\PowerShellScripts\LastLogon\Results" -Recurse |
Where-Object CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-0) | Remove-Item -
ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#The Login Profile is filtered here
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_NetworkLoginProfile -ComputerName $ComputerName|
#Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.LogonServer -like $ComputerName}|
Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.FullName -notlike "*Agvance*"} | 
Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.FullName -notlike "*Sophos*"} |
Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.FullName -ne "AgvAdmin"} |
Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.FullName -ne ""} | 
Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "*ssi1*"}|
Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "*ssi2*"}|
Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "*ssi3*"}|
Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "*ssi4*"}|
Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "*ssi5*"}|
Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "*ssi6*"}|
Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "*ssi7*"}|
Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "*ssi8*"}|
Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "*ssi9*"}|
Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "*ssiadmin*"}|
Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Name -notlike "*SYSTEM*"} |
Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Name -notlike "*SERVICE*"} |
Where-Object -FilterScript {!
[System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.LastLogon)} |
Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastLogon) -ge 
$AuditDate} | 
Select-Object  Name,LogonServer,@{label='LastLogon';expression=
{$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastLogon)}} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | sort-
object Name | Export-Csv 
C:\PowerShellScripts\Lastlogon\Results\LastLogon.csv -NoTypeInformation

#Extra filter to filter out SSI users 
#Import-Csv C:\PowerShellScripts\Results\LastLogon.csv | Where-Object 
{$_.Name -notlike "*ssi*"} |Export-Csv 
C:\PowerShellScripts\Lastlogon\Results\LastLogon.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force

#The user count is created here
$number = (Import-Csv C:\PowerShellScripts\Lastlogon\Results\LastLogon.csv | 
measure | % { $_.Count})

#The file is renamed to include computername, date, and user count
rename-item -path C:\PowerShellScripts\Lastlogon\Results\LastLogon.csv -NewName C:\PowerShellScripts\Lastlogon\Results\LastLogon-$ComputerName-$CurrentDate-UserCount-$number.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give this a try and see if it provides what you need.

```
$time = (Get-Date) – (New-TimeSpan -Day 30)

# You can additional filters in ? { $_.Properties[1].Value -ne 'SYSTEM' } by
#   modifying it with -and statements 
#   i.e. ? { ($_.Properties[1].Value -ne 'SYSTEM') -and  ($_.Properties[1].Value -ne 'USER')}
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Security';ID=4672;starttime=$time} -ComputerName $ComputerName  | ? { $_.Properties[1].Value -ne 'SYSTEM' } | select @{N='User';E={$_.Properties[1].Value}}, @{N='TimeCreated';E={$_.TimeCreated}}
```

Comment: That would work but I am getting a lot of DWM - XXXX showing up.  I am not sure if those are actual users or not but I do recognize some of the others in there.

Comment: DWM stands for "Desktop Windows Manager". These can be filtered out the same as the "System" account. A quote from Wikipedia "Desktop Window Manager (DWM, previously Desktop Compositing Engine or DCE) is the window manager in Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 10 that enables the use of hardware acceleration to render the graphical user interface of Windows." [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Window_Manager)

Comment: As for the other users, can you query AD using 'Get-ADUser -Filter {samaccountname -like "*USERNAME*"}' to check if they are valid accounts? They could be service accounts. If they are not in AD, you can post them here and I will see if I recognize them.

Comment: That script does bring back a few users but it does not seem to show all of them and it only shows up to the 25th.  It could be that that event log can only hold so many.

Comment: As for only going back to the 25th, the system does only allow the logs to grow to a certain size at which point it starts overwriting entries. You can see the properties by: 1) logging on to the server; 2) going to the event log (security); 3) right click on the security event log; 4) click on properties. You will see the "Maximum log size (KB)" field. After the log reaches this size it will start overwriting. Increase it if you need to keep entries for longer. You can also set it to archive the log so that you can reference it later.

Comment: As for not showing all users, the event ID 4672 only shows logons with special permissions (administrators, auditors, etc.). You could try filtering for ID 4624 as well (I believe that is any logon that does not have special permissions). I can't test it on my servers because I only allow admins to log on. [4624(S): An account was successfully logged on.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-security/auditing/event-4624)

Comment: I did edit it to show only the 4624 logs and that did show a lot more of the users.  I believe this is pointing me to the right direction.  I am going to try to see if I can filter it to show the last login of each user.